# SQL Data Insertion in a table B on basis of change in a column value of Table A

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table A with attributes studentID(PK),name,address and allotment_status(value can be zero or one) and Table B with roomid(PK),studentID(FK) and roomno now I want that whenever the value of allotment_status is updated to one a new row is inserted in table B and whenever it is set to zero if row exists in table B it gets deleted.

Comment: You're probably looking for a trigger  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html, but there can be performance issues associated with this.  An alternative is to run a stored procedure periodically that looks for rows in table B that should exist, but don't yet, and create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of way to create trigger on tableA, with update/insert/delete event. This is pure database solution.  Whether it's good design or bad depends on your business requirements. So weight it thoroughly before making a decision. The other solution could be to code in your PHP application layer, but I have less experience on that, so would like to avoid answer code level details.

```
  CREATE TRIGGER on_tablea_updateb after/before INSERT/update ON tableA FOR EACH ROW  // your business logic goes here condition....; END IF;//
```